# What permissions does a file written with fstream have?

Tags: c++, linux, stl, fstream

Suppose I create a file for writing like this:

```
std::ofstream my_file("filename", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::trunc);
```

How are the permissions of this file determined? I've had a program running overnight generating files about once a minute - some are 0644 but others are 0660, and there's nothing in my code that should make it change. (I've seen that some implementations allow a third argument to set the file permissions - I'm using gcc 4.1.2 which doesn't appear to support this).

Comment: As others have said, the attributes depend on umask. Since you said that your code does not modify file attributes, perhaps another applications does this?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense - not sure what my program was doing, but I'll keep an eye on it in case it happens again.

Comment: I did see my original "problem" again - I think it was caused by building and running my app against slightly different versions of the same shared library, which was starting to cause other weird stuff to happen. I still think the question was worth asking though :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the [umask](http://linux.die.net/man/1/umask).

Answer (score 0):

default attrs are set with `umask` command. it not explains your files attrs changes, but still may be useful for you